# Properly implementing/initializing lots of new variables, taken from RadioGroups and Spinners

Tags: android, eclipse, radio-button, initialization, android-spinner

I am developing a simple questionnaire-like app which includes lots of radio buttons joined into groups and spinners. I have multiple activities (6); some of them having RBs and some Spinners to let the user answer the questions.
The following step, which I have trouble with, is how to fetch lots of selections (of all the radio buttons/choices) and possibly do that in a for loop (so I don't have to initialize each new variable 30+ times in a row for just one activity). I've already assigned IDs to all of the views, but am having a hard time how to actually fetch the selection, initialize a new var corresponding to the selection (let's say radio button 1 in radio group 1 gives me a new variable with a value of 1) and then make the variables available to all of the activities (should I use global when initializing?).

My failed attempt on generating 10 variables for the first "page"

```
    public void goTo2(View v) {
    checkRB();          
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Vprasalnik1.this, Vprasalnik2.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
    finish();
  }

public void checkRB()
{
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        RadioButton "vRB" + i; //I'd like to loop and initialize vars by adding a number to them (vRB1, vRB2, ...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put variables into array like a

```
int size = 9; 
RadioButton[] views = new RadioButton[size];  
public static checkRB()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        views[i] = (RadioButton)findViewByID(...);//For example
    }
}
```

Or make a structure :

```
public class Choise
{
    int mRadioButtonChoise;
    int mSpinnerChoise;
}
```

And use something like this:

```
...
Choise c = new Choise();
c.mRadioButtonChoise = yourRadioButtonID;
c.mSpinnerChoise = youtSpinnerChoiseID;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of RadioButtons then you can get all the values at the same time, however initializing them will have to be manual.

```
RadioButton rb[];
boolean rbc[];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    rbc=new boolean[200];
    rb=new RadioButton[200]();
    rb[0]=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb[1]=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb[2]=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    rb[3]=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb4);
    // many more.
}

public void checkRB()
{
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
         rbc[i]=rb.isChecked(); //I'd like to loop and initialize vars by adding a number to them (vRB1, vRB2, ...)
    }
}
```

Then before starting your intent add all relevant data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a variable to identify a resource:

```
RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[size];  

public static checkRB()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {   
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("vRB" + i, "id", context.getPackageName())
        rb[i] = (RadioButton)findViewByID(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to cramp up the radio buttons activity, so that it finally works. If anyone is interested - I've used tags in xml code to properly assign values (1, 2 and 3 for each group of buttons) and managed to get an output in my testToast. At least I didn't have to initialize all of the variables manually - I've been saving the values into an ArrayList and then appended to them via StringBuilder.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help - it turned out I've needed a bit more research, testing and teasing my half-awake brain.

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.v3_btn1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
                {
                    tmpRGid = "radioGroup_v3q" + i;
                    tmp2RGid = getResources().getIdentifier(tmpRGid, "id", getPackageName());
                    RGid = (RadioGroup) findViewById(tmp2RGid);
                    selectedOption = RGid.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    RBid = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedOption);
                    addToIDList.add((String)RBid.getTag());
                }

                String testToast = "";
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append("Vaša izbira (");
                for (int z=0; z < addToIDList.size(); z++) {
                    testToast = addToIDList.get(z);
                    builder.append(testToast + ", ");
                    }
                builder.setLength(builder.length() - 2);
                builder.append(") je bila shranjena.");

                Toast.makeText(Vprasalnik3.this, builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: By the way, sorry for some parts of the code - it is in Slovene and not in English.